# Doesn't "npm run build" run before yarn add?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm trying to install the package I made from my github repository.

I wrote it with typescript and added

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  }
```

to its package.json.

If you run `npm install me/myrepo"`, `npm run build`(means `tsc`) will run automatically before an installation right?
Then, what about when you run `yarn add https://github.com/me/myrepo/`?
I expected the same move but it doesn't seem like that.

Do you have any way to build it when you run "yarn add"?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself.
My problem wasn't about between npm and yarn, but the way to specify `tsc` to `scripts`.

It must be like below:

```
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build": "npm run tsc"
  }
```

as if you just simply specify `tsc` to `scripts`, it means a global dependency of tsc.

Answer (score 0):

Running *yarn add* will install the dependency and add it to package.json (1). You will have to run *npm run build* or similarly "yarn run build" after adding the package.

(1) https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't have enough words. I'm talking about the build of packages that I install. I thought the package will be built when I install it even if it doesn't have built files(for example, ./dist directory). I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: And I'm trying to install the package from a github repository.